# How to Programmatically on/off talkback from main activity

Tags: android

I would like to programmatically enable/disable "setting>Accessibility>talkback" Services.
There is a part in my application where I want talkback service 'ON' and in the other part of my app, I want normal behaviour(i.e without talkback).
I could not found any solution of this problem.
Please help!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why you want to toggle ON/OFF for the whole talkback service.

An alternate approach could be to turn off accessibility (talkback) for an individual Android widget component such as `TextView` in your application.

To achieve this, simply add In your XML file, set the importance to "no" for a specific `TextView`.

```
<TextView
    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
    ... />
```

Or you want runtime control, use below from your JAVA code:

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

This way, your application has finer control over Accessibility while honoring the user's Accessibility Settings.

NOTE: Above API/XML Attribute was introduced in Android Since API 16,  And with revision 22 it's now in the v4 support library. http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: this works. Note: we must to set up before clicking to a View.